# contentEditable does not wrap first line in tags

Tags: html, contenteditable

I have a div with the attribute contentEditable set.

The trouble I am having is that the first line I type does not get wrapped in tags, but the subsequent lines do.

So typing:

```
qwerty
zxcv
asdfg
```

Results in:

```
<div class="editable" contentEditable="true">
    qwerty
    <div>zxcv</div>
    <div>asdfg</div>
</div>
```

So I need the `qwerty` line to become `<div>qwerty</div>`

Comment: This is still a problem in Chrome 38. Not that I'm punting IE in any way but it was inserting P tags sensibly in IE 7. I fail to comprehend how it is possible that Chrome has not yet got this basic multi-line functionality right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start with an element that contains a `div` inside it like this:

`<div class="editable" contentEditable="true">
    <div></div>
</div>`

the first line you type will end up being wraped in a `div`.

**UPDATE:**

This is browser specific. While it did work in most browsers at the time the question was posted, it does not necessarily work anymore in the latest browser version. Best way to tell is to just test it.

Comment: I had done that, and it does work. Wasn't necessarily the ideal solution I was hoping fir but it works. Thanks

Comment: that works only unless you remove all content from div. after that it will include `<br>` at first line and then the first line will be unwrapped again.

Comment: This only works if your div contains a <br> tag ```<div><br></div>```

Answer (score 8):

I had issues in Chrome just adding a div. It only worked if your div contains a br tag:

```
<div class="editable" contentEditable="true">
  <div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

@nicholas_r is right, deleting the last character in the editable div will also delete the div added at the beginning. You can avoid this, by catching the last 'backspace'. A simple solution using jquery to do it:

```
$(".editable").on('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 8 && $(this).html() == '<div><br></div>') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: One little note, `$(this).html()` should be `$(this).html().trim()` or it does not work

Comment: Unfortunately, highlighting and deleting does remove this.

Answer (score 4):

If it helps, running the following will let you wrap unwrapped divs . If you trigger it on keypress or something like that, it'll work even if the user removes all content from the div.

```
 $(".editable").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
 }).wrap('<div></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this and it works really well for making sure there's always a div wrapper on the first line of text.

This way if the user clicks into the field and its blank (initial state) it'll put a blank space in, to make sure that their cursor is inside of the new div.

```
$editable.on('focus', function() {
  if ($(this).text().trim() === '') {
    console.log('editable is blank, insert a div');
    $(this).append($('<div>&nbsp;</div>'));  
  }
});
```

You can remove the leading space (if it matters) before saving the data.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming across this in 2017, or later, none of these answers worked for me in Chrome, and those trying to come up with a smart solution didn't cover all my cases.

Although only tested in Chrome, and a little rough, this covers the 3 major scenarios:

1. User tries to delete content in an empty `contenteditable` div.
2. User tries to delete all content in a `contenteditable` div using either `ctrl+a Delete` or `ctrl+a Backspace`.
3. User tries to delete all content in a `contenteditable` div by replacing full selection `ctrl-a` with a letter of their choice.

A [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hcn4015d/) demo.

```
document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  if(e.which == 8 && document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML=="<div><br></div>"){  // 8 is backspace
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  if (window.getSelection && e.which == 8 || e.which == 46 && window.getSelection){ // 8 is backspace, 46 is delete
    let selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    let editorText = document.getElementById("editor").innerText;

    if (editorText == selection){
      document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML="<div><br></div>"
      console.log("prevented a ctrl+a delete")
    }
  else if (window.getSelection){
    let selection = window.getSelection().toString();
    let editorText = document.getElementById("editor").innerText;

    if (editorText == selection){
      document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML="<div>"+e.which+"</div>";
      console.log("safely did a ctrl+a " + e.which)
    }
  }

  e.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

Comment: Try my answer below. I think it handles all your issues without having to prevent any default user/ browser behaviors. Quick jump to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47685420/3193156

Answer (score 1):

Most of these solutions were not working for me in Chrome in 2017 (version 61.x), and [Kasper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42041626/136590) seemed too messy to me.

As far as I can tell, a simple check for `""` or `<br>` on the `input` event handles every possible case, including backspace, delete, and copy-and-paste:

```
$("[contenteditable='true']")
  .on("input", function ()
  {
    var $editable = $(this);
    if ($editable.html().trim() === "" || $editable.html().trim() === "<br>")
      $editable.html($("<div><br></div>"));
  })
  .trigger("input");
```

Note that I also trigger the `input` event upon initialization to make sure that the initial content is set correctly, but that may or may not be necessary depending on your particular needs.

https://jsfiddle.net/25ujvrn0/

Comment: This is _the_ answer. It is the simplest answer that works in all situations. I wish I could upvote this twice.

Comment: @JG.cods Are you referring to the `<input placeholder="" />` attribute? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefplaceholder That attribute only works natively for `input` and `textarea` elements. If you want `placeholder` to work on div and other non-input elements, you will have to write your own custom code to handle that, including how you handle the "input is empty" check that I outlined above in my answer. There's no way for me to handle placeholders in my solution without knowing how your custom placeholder code works.

Comment: im pertaining on the placeholder not on input tag :) . and yes contenteditable have it but will not work rigth away. you have to put style to work with placeholder and contenteditable you can checkout  this stackoverflow question and answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726174/placeholder-for-contenteditable-div/24827239

Comment: @JG.cods So just like I said, your link provides a customized hack to make `placeholder` work. It does this by defining a CSS pseudo-element when the contenteditable div is empty. Unfortunately, that hack is directly at odds with the goal of this question and my solution here: We're trying to make sure that the contenteditable div is *never empty* and always has at least `<div><br></div>` as its content. To make a similar hack work with this solution, you would have to replace the CSS `:empty` rule with a JS check for the empty state and define an empty class: https://jsfiddle.net/d1ocypr4/

Answer (score 1):

**Context**
This is a solution to the OP that ensures the first line in a content editable div always gets wrapped and fixes common bugs like:

- Un-wrapped first line after erasing editor and immediately typing.
- Line break added after erasing editor.
- All of the issues mentioned by Kasper Fredenslund:

  - Ctrl + A + Del
  - Ctrl + A + Backspace
  - Ctrl + A + Any typing the user does

It uses event listeners to catch when a user focuses on the editor and when they leave. For more context please read the comments in the code.

**Code**
Below is a full working fiddle of the code. My original example can be found at this [JS Fiddle page](https://jsfiddle.net/blizzardengle/xLgtt1oq/2/).

```js
// On Dom Ready
document.getElementById('editor').addEventListener('focusin', checkEditor);
document.getElementById('editor').addEventListener('focusout', checkEditor);

function checkEditor() {
  // Get the DOM element that the user is in
  // Allows you to have multiple editos on one page
  // Next 3 lines of code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1553668/3193156
  var e = event || window.event;
  var elem = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (elem.nodeType == 3) {
    elem = elem.parentNode;
  } // Defeat Safari bug
  // Grab the elements inner HTML
  var html = elem.innerHTML
    // If html is empty or does not start with a div see if we need to fix something
  if (html == '' || html.substr(0, 5) != '<div>') {
    notify('Running editor checks.');
    var index;
    // Catch bug where a line break is added after a user uses backspace to wipe the editor
    if (html.substr(0, 4) == '<br>') {
      notify('Removed line break.');
      index = html.indexOf('\n');
      // If there are any lines after this line break save them
      if (index > -1) {
        html = html.substr(html.indexOf('\n') + 1);
      } else {
        html = '';
      }
      elem.innerHTML = html;
      // If everything is ok return otherwise keep processing
      if (html != '' && html.substr(0, 5) == '<div>') {
        return;
      }
    }
    // Catch bug where first line after erasing editor does not get wrapped
    index = html.indexOf('\n');
    if (index > -1) {
      notify('Wrapped the fist line, did not check the rest.');
      html = html = '<div>' + html.substr(0, html.indexOf('\n') + 1) + '</div>' + html.substr(html.indexOf('\n') + 1);
      elem.innerHTML = html;
      return;
    } else {
      html = html.trim();
      if (html.length > 0) {
        notify('Wrapped the fist line');
        html = '<div>' + html.trim() + '</div>';
        elem.innerHTML = html;
        return;
      }
    }
    // If we made it here the editor shold be considered empty, reset it
    notify('Editor reset.');
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.innerHTML = '<br>';
    elem.appendChild(div);
  }
}

function notify(msg) {
  var div = document.createElement('DIV');
  div.innerHTML = msg;
  document.getElementById('messages').appendChild(div);
}
```

```css
#editor {
  width: 90%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">

</div>
<div id="messages">
</div>
```

**To-Do / Missing**
This solution answers the OP and does not account for the following use cases:

- Checking results after pasting in content; this would need to go line by line and wrap everything.
- Checking any other lines after the first; not common but I believe you can end up with and un-wrapped line at the end of your content depending in browser.

Comment: working but,  if you have placeholder it not show properly

Answer (score 0):

Just simple `<div></div>` won't work.

If you looking for jQuery solution, here is the code:

```
$('.contenteditable').on 'focus', ->
  if $(@).text().trim() == ''
    $(@).append($('<div><br /></div>'))
```