# contenteditable does not show pseudoselector :before in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, pseudo-element

I wanted to add a behavior for input with placeholder to a contenteditable field.

Not a problem and it is done with the following CSS

```
<div contentEditable="true" data-placeholder="Title"></div>
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
  content:attr(data-placeholder);
  color:grey;
}
```

which is for every element with an attribute `contenteditable` that is `true` and also does not have children and not focused insert a text that is equal to the text in `data-placholder`.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7B4FR/) is available. On FF, Chrome and IE 11 it works nice, but in Safari (from 5 to 7) I see the following bug. When I click:

- click on editable
- write something
- click away (it works properly)
- then go back to contenteditable
- remove all the text
- click away

Than my contenteditable is empty. (In all other browser it has `Title` inside). Note that if you just click on editable and clickaway, it behaves correctly.

No idea why it behaves this way and also how to fix it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20726174/2126792

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue where the element does not register as being empty. You can fix it with a simple jquery function call to empty the element:

```
$input.empty();
```

See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23879580/2126792) for a detailed explaination.

Here your working [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7B4FR/16/).