# How to add placeholder to html content inside <iframe>

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, frontend, placeholder

I have an iframe with a Doctype with body and html content inside as follows:

```
<iframe>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <style id="mceDefaultStyles" type="text/css"></style>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <body>
        <p>
        <br data-mce-bogus="1">
        </p>
    </body>
    <grammarly-desktop-integration data-grammarly-shadow-root="true"></grammarly-desktop-integration></html>
</iframe>
```

Inside I have editable content in the iframe which edits p text content as if it a textarea with html content was. I want to implement something as a placeholder: "Edit html" on it. I've tried different approaches but none working as implementing css or script inserting content in the iframe with  to try to edit the content dynamically but nothing works.

Is there a proper approach to solve or a right way to do it?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: Which part exactly is the problem now, creating a placeholder for a contenteditable element (if so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726174/placeholder-for-contenteditable-div), or getting it implemented inside the iframe?

Comment: Getting it implemented inside the iframe.