# how to get multiline html of a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, contenteditable

write this inside `ed`

```
lorem  
ipsum
```

and click the button. Result:

```
lorem<p>ipsum</p>
```

how to get this:

```
<p>lorem</p>
<p>ipsum</p>
```

I'm on Chrome, last version

```js
document.execCommand("defaultParagraphSeparator", false, "p");

$('button').on('click', () => {
    let a = $('#ed').html();
    $('#btex').val(a);
    console.log(a);
});
```

```css
.ed{
min-height:25px;
background:gold;
outline:none;
}
.btex{
display:block;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<br><br>
<div class='ed' id='ed' contenteditable autofocus></div>
<br>
<textarea class='btex' id='btex'></textarea>
```

Comment: FYI This works in Firefox with paragraphs wrapping the first line

Comment: @Dominik, thanks, unfortunatelly I'm on Chrome

Comment: @qadenza it's just all about the first line of the div? Because it works well after the first line.

Comment: @oguzhancerit - no - try with `lorem ipsum dolor` - each line is joined in the result, there is no any end of line

Comment: @qadenza I got. may be you can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592254/contenteditable-does-not-wrap-first-line-in-tags

Comment: @oguzhancerit - your link - wrapping firs line - maybe works ih Firefox but  unfortunatelly I'm on Chrome. Plus - there is no solution for end of lines for each ofl lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the input at the space and then loop over the resulting array elements, wrapping each with paragraphs.

```js
document.execCommand("defaultParagraphSeparator", false, "p");

$('button').on('click', () => {
    // Split the text of the div where there are spaces
    // and return the parts in an array
    let a = $('#ed').html().replace("</p>", "").split("<p>");
    
    // Loop through the array and add each item (wrapped in <p></p>) to a new array
    // Then, join that resulting array's elements with nothing to create a string.
    $('#btex').val(a.map(function(item){ return "<p>" + item + "</p>" }).join("\n"));
});
```

```css
.ed{
min-height:25px;
background:gold;
outline:none;
}
.btex{
display:block;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<br><br>
<div class='ed' id='ed' contenteditable autofocus></div>
<br>
<textarea class='btex' id='btex'></textarea>
```

Comment: pls try - that's not at all what i want in result

Comment: @qadenza I have tried. It's not clear what you expect. Please clarify.

Comment: pls read in my question - `how to get this:`...In your solution I'm gettin this - `[
  "loremipsum"
]`

Comment: did you try your snippet? I'm getting this - `[   "loremipsum" ]`

Comment: in textarea I'm getting this - `<p>loremipsum</p>`

Comment: my chrome version - `Version 86.0.4240.198 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: can I send to you a result screenshot somewhere?

Comment: @qadenza Please try the answer one more time. I think I finally get what you are saying.

Comment: almost - that's it - but is it possible to get each `<p>...</p>` in new lines

Comment: @qadenza Answer updated. You just need to also add the JavaScript escape code for a new line `\n`.