# Safe way to pass this variable to javascript method for all browsers

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this `ASPX`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function clickCheckBox(event) {
        if (event.className == "icon-check-empty icon-large"){
            event.className = "icon-ok icon-large";
        }else if(event.className == "icon-ok icon-large"){
            event.className = "icon-check-empty icon-large";
        } else {
            alert("Problem:  " + event.className);//TODO:  log error
        }
    }

</script>

...

<div class="check-box-column camera-column-padding">
    <span id="spCheckBox" runat="server">
        <i id="cameraSelectCheckBox" class="<%# (bool)Eval("Checked") ? "icon-ok icon-large" : "icon-check-empty icon-large" %>"   style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="clickCheckBox(this)"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

My concern is primarily for the `javascript` portion.  I pass in `this` to the function call (which is `event`).  Then I just do `event.className` to change the class type.  I was looking at [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1553668/2498729).  I was wondering if it is ok to do this will all browsers as is or should I do it differently for different browsers like in the linked solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is fine. The other answer advocates [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), which certainly has its good points, but isn't a requirement to get working code.

One suggestion would be to call the argument `element` instead of `event`, since calling it `event` is likely to lead to confusion, since it implies that the argument would be the event object, not the target element.