# Dynamically acquire the ElementId from an html element with JS

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to dynamically acquire the name of the element that calls a function with the onClick event?

I need to write a code to reuse massively in a form to validate the content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the onclick calling object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553661/how-to-get-the-onclick-calling-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this by passing an event to the respective onClick function as stated below.

```
<a href="#" id="testLink" onclick="HandleLink(event)">Link</a>

function HandleLink(event)
{
    var x = event.target;
    alert(x.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tough to say this is exactly what you are looking for, but something like this?

```
onClickHandler(event) {
  var domNode = event.targetElement;
  var name = domNode.getAttribute("name");
  // do what you will with that
}
```

Getting the element this way makes sure it was what you clicked on - using `this` can be different depending on if you bound scope to the method along the way somewhere

Comment: If you set `onClickHandler` with `addEventListener` then `this` will point to `targetElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer with an example if this is what you are looking for:

Html:

```
<input name='Foo" type='button' value='Click Me' onclick='bar(this)'>
```

JS:

```
function bar(elem) {
    alert('Clicked by' + elem.name);
}
```

You can use parentNode to navigate in your form.