# Javascript to Change Class without use of ID Tag

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to change the class of HTML elements without the use of the ID tag because I have so many of these elements. I would like to have something simple like this but the code is not working.

```
<li ><a onclick="ChangeClass()" href="/Default.aspx">Home</a></li>

<script>
        function ChangeClass(){
            this.className = "active";
        } 
</script>
```

EDIT: Sorry, That was a type. My code did have the brackets but still isn't working.

EDIT2: Thanks for the quick replies, I will look at all of them and take notes.

Comment: You can use the [element/document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) API to get a list of all those elements that you want to fiddle with their `className` or `classList` property.

Comment: I'd say you need onclick="ChangeClass(this)" and then function ChangeClass(elm) {elm.className=.....}

Comment: `this` does not mean what you think it does there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the onclick calling object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553661/how-to-get-the-onclick-calling-object)

Comment: Lexical this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'this' here is pointing to window object. you can use call/apply to change the context of this.

check this snippet

```js
 function ChangeClass(event) {
   this.className = "active";
 }
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<li><a href="/Default.aspx" class="default" onclick="ChangeClass.call(this)">Home</a>
</li>

<script>
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: you don't need the `.call()` `ChangeClass(this)` is fine

Comment: In that case . function needs to accept a parameter and this still points to window object.to have the minimal changes we can do this approach

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript `this` refers to the element containing the action.
The way you use it in your function like that, you are not getting the DOM element clicked's scope, but only the function scope.
The `this` you are referencing to in the `onClick` handler is not the DOM element you think it is. You need to Change your code to this:

```
<li ><a onclick="ChangeClass(this)" href="/Default.aspx">Home</a></li>

<script>
        function ChangeClass(element){
            element.className = "active";
        } 
</script>
```