# How do I target specific buttons based on which is clicked with only one function?

Tags: javascript, function

So I'm revising a tic-tac-toe game I made a while ago and I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of repetitive functions. Is there anyway to target a specific button based on which is clicked?

```
function XonCell() {
document.getElementById("cell").innerHTML = 'X'
}
```

```
<button id="cell" onclick="XonSquare()">-</button>
<button id="cell" onclick="XonSquare()">-</button>
<button id="cell" onclick="XonSquare()">-</button>
```

So how would I make it to if the first button was clicked X would replace the first button's text and if the second was clicked X would replace the second button's text, and so on for all the buttons?

All I need is for the X to appear on the button that is clicked without multiple functions. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the onclick calling object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553661/how-to-get-the-onclick-calling-object)

Comment: That looks good but how would I apply that to a button and not a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `event.target.id` when you pass event in function,
each button must have its own id.

example:

```js
 function XonSquare(event) {
        document.getElementById(event.target.id).innerHTML = "X";
      }
```

```html
 <button id="cell1" onclick="XonSquare(event)">-</button>
    <button id="cell2" onclick="XonSquare(event)">-</button>
    <button id="cell3" onclick="XonSquare(event)">-</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
inner = document.getElementById("cell").value;
inner.innerHTML ='X';
```

This code should make the value of the button element be "X".

Comment: Hmmm I tried it but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of HTML IDs is that they are unique, and therefore addressable.  You're giving all cells the same ID.  You should give them all the same class, but unique IDs, so your function can change the appropriate ID's content to an X.

Code example:

```
<button id="cell1" class="cell" onClick="XonSquare(1)">-</button>
<button id="cell2" class="cell" onClick="XonSquare(2)">-</button>
<button id="cell3" class="cell" onClick="XonSquare(3)">-</button>
```

That way you can have your function target the appropriate cell.

Comment: How then would I apply it to my code?